# How to compile kernel with debug symbols for my own OS?

Tags: gcc, operating-system, gdb, ld

Hi I'm a beginner and trying to write a Linux like kernel.

I use Qemu as my emulator and currently debug in a assembly level.

However, by previous experience, I can debug Linux kernel with Qemu at source code (.c files) level.

So I would like to ask if I can do it with my own kernel, so that I can debug it with efficiency.

In order to provide more info, the following is my compilation script:

```
# Complie head.S
    gcc -E ./PysicCodes/head.S > head.s
    as --64 -o head.o head.s
    gcc -E ./PysicCodes/AP_Boot.S > AP_Boot.s
    as --64 -o AP_Boot.o AP_Boot.s
# Compile main program
    gcc -mcmodel=large -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m64 -c ./PysicCodes/*.c
# Interrupt hander requires general register only(since no XMM,SEE registers are saved)
    gcc -mcmodel=large -fno-builtin -fno-stack-protector -m64 -mgeneral-regs-only -c ./PysicCodes/g_reg_only/*.c
# Linkage: Must put head.o at first, so that kernel start at head.o
    ld -b elf64-x86-64 -z muldefs -o system head.o 8529A.o ACPI.o AP_Boot.o APIC.o cpu.o INT.o keyboard.o main.o Mem.o PCI.o Printk.o SMP.o Task.o Time.o TSS.o fat32.o -T ./PysicCodes/Kernel.lds
# Dump kernel
    objcopy -I elf64-x86-64 -S -R ".eh_frame" -R ".comment" -O binary system Kernel.bin
```

Thanks for anyone who would spend time on helping. Any extra information needed, please comment.

Answer (score 0):

Currently I tried to add `-ggdb3` as the compiling and linking options.

Furthermore, using the compiled object as the option for `gdb`

It simply worked.

In addition, adding `"miDebuggerServerAddress": "localhost:1234"` into Vscode's "launch.json" file, it actually can connect to Qemu and debug c code in vscode.

However only 1 problem, that vscode will run Qemu at start, so I have to press pause button as soon as I can after start debugger, and using "-exec" to put a hardware break-point.

There is an [issue](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-cpptools/issues/5471) on git and currently haven't see an answer.